# addgroup vs groupadd

Tags: permissions, group

I happen to know [there is a slight difference between `adduser` and `useradd`](https://serverfault.com/questions/218993/whats-the-difference-between-useradd-and-adduser).
(i.e., `adduser` has additional features to `useradd`, such as creating a home directory.)

Then what is the relation between `addgroup` and `groupadd`?
Is there a preferred way to create a group?

Comment: I strongly dislike this particular namescheme. Can never remember which is the more primitive of the utilities.

Comment: @dubiousjim - How I do it is I remember that all convenience ones start with "add", so the primitive ones all start with the thing they are changing, ie "user'', "group",  etc.

Comment: I find it easier to remember which is more primitive by placing the commands in alphabetical order. 

Alphabetically 'adduser' and 'deluser' would come first, so are more recent/higher level. Whereas 'useradd' and 'userdel' are the older/lower level commands.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

On most distribution `adduser` and `addgroup` are interactive 'convenience' wrappers around the commands `useradd` and `groupadd`.

You can find addgroup using the command `which addgroup`, on my machine (Ubuntu 11.04) this lives in `/usr/sbin/addgroup`.

On my box `addgroup` is a perl script that prompts for various options (interactively) before invoking the `groupadd` command.

`groupadd` is usually preferable for scripting (say, if you wan't to create users in batch), whereas `addgroup` is more user friendly (especially if you are unfamiliar with all the options and flags).

Of course `addgroup` also takes many options via the command when you invoke it, but it is primarily intended as an interactive script.

Interestingly on my box `addgroup` is a symlink to `adduser`, the script checks the name it was invoked under and performs different actions accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

`groupadd` is more preferable for better cross-linux and sometimes cross-unix systems compatibility.

`addgroup` is often just a wrapper over `groupadd` (written in perl, [source code here](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adduser/tree/adduser)).

In the same way, `useradd` is more preferable than `adduser` - [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345974/what-is-the-difference-between-adduser-and-useradd)